# How to resolve "Tried all: 4 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: XXXXX port: 443"

Tags: web-services, weblogic12c, soa-suite

In my SOA process (Oracle SOA Suite 12c), I have a rest adapter that calls an `https` service. During invoke i am getting the following error:

```
oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: 4 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: myresourceUrl port: 443
```

Is this error because i am connecting to HTTPS service? Can this be due to certificate issue? 
I have already added the  services' certificate in cacerts

Comment: Maybe test if Postman (or similar REST client)  can hit that web service and confirm that works before debugging SOA.

Comment: Hi Joe , I tried with simple REST Client and i got  "The owner of this website has banned your access based on your browser's signature ".If I hit the URL directly from a browser or through SOAPUI , it works

Comment: so there does seem t be an issue hitting the site. You would need to resolve that for SOA to work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the hostname in the endpoint configured in the rest adapter? The error says that it fails to connect to the server `myresourceUrl`? Is this the correct host name?